# PHP get values by key from different structured multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I get multidimensional arrays with **different structures** like these:

array 1:

```
array(1) {
  ["BrowseNode"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
    string(9) "364935031"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(17) "Taschen & Schalen"
    ["Ancestors"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["BrowseNode"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
        string(9) "364918031"
        ["Name"]=>
        string(13) "HandyzubehÃ¶r"
        ["Ancestors"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["BrowseNode"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(10) "1384526031"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(17) "Handys & ZubehÃ¶r"
            ["Ancestors"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["BrowseNode"]=>
              array(4) {
                ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                string(6) "569604"
                ["Name"]=>
                string(10) "Kategorien"
                ["IsCategoryRoot"]=>
                string(1) "1"
                ["Ancestors"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["BrowseNode"]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                    string(6) "562066"
                    ["Name"]=>
                    string(17) "Elektronik & Foto"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

array 2:

```
array(1) {
  ["BrowseNode"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
      string(9) "122877031"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(6) "DÃ¼fte"
      ["Children"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["BrowseNode"]=>
        array(6) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(10) "2795107031"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(5) "Damen"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(10) "2795100031"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(6) "Herren"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(2) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(10) "4695227031"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(19) "Kerzen & RaumdÃ¼fte"
          }
          [3]=>
          array(2) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(10) "2795099031"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(6) "Kinder"
          }
          [4]=>
          array(2) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(9) "591313031"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(18) "ParfÃ¼mzerstÃ¤uber"
          }
          [5]=>
          array(2) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(9) "591280031"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(4) "Sets"
          }
        }
      }
      ["Ancestors"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["BrowseNode"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
          string(8) "84231031"
          ["Name"]=>
          string(10) "Kategorien"
          ["IsCategoryRoot"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["Ancestors"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["BrowseNode"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
              string(8) "84230031"
              ["Name"]=>
              string(6) "Beauty"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
      string(9) "161329031"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(11) "Lidschatten"
      ["Ancestors"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["BrowseNode"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
          string(9) "161320031"
          ["Name"]=>
          string(5) "Augen"
          ["Ancestors"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["BrowseNode"]=>
            array(3) {
              ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
              string(9) "122880031"
              ["Name"]=>
              string(7) "Make-Up"
              ["Ancestors"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["BrowseNode"]=>
                array(4) {
                  ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                  string(8) "84231031"
                  ["Name"]=>
                  string(10) "Kategorien"
                  ["IsCategoryRoot"]=>
                  string(1) "1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can get all values from `Name` keys to a string? I have seen at least 30 different structures so far so it's impossible to loop the arrays in a strict way

Comment: Pierre Maniche ist ein kleiner Kelleraffe ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That array is organized as a tree. Trees are best handled by a recursive function. This will do:

```php
function extract_Name($arr, $path, &$result)
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if ($k == "Name")
        {
            $result[$path . "/" . $k] = $v;
        }
        else if (is_array($v))
        {
            extract_Name($v, $path . "/" . $k, $result);
        }
    }
}

$result = array();
extract_Name($your_struc, "", $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Sample output:

```
array(5) {
  ["/BrowseNode/Name"]=>
  string(17) "Taschen & Schalen"
  ["/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Name"]=>
  string(13) "Handyzubehör"
  ["/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Name"]=>
  string(17) "Handys & Zubehör"
  ["/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Name"]=>
  string(10) "Kategorien"
  ["/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Name"]=>
  string(17) "Elektronik & Foto"
}
```

If you only want names without the path that leads to them, you can simply replace:

```
$result[$path . "/" . $k] = $v;
```

with:

```
$result[] = $v;
```

The output in this case will be:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "Taschen & Schalen"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "Handyzubehör"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "Handys & Zubehör"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "Kategorien"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "Elektronik & Foto"
}
```